# Django table relation manytomany with two fields reference

Tags: python, django, database, manytomanyfield

I have a question related to database relation in Django.
There are in total three tables, see below. The relation between KbMeta and Tdb is successfully established through Foreignkey method. However I dont know how to manage the relation between Posd and Tdb. The position 'hg' and 'pos' are unique in the Posd table but they are not unique in Tdb table. However when I compare the fields HG, and POS I should get the right reference. The following method doesn't work in Tdb table:

```
posd = models.ManyToManyField(Posd, through='Posd', through_fields=('hg','pos')) # This is wrong, doesn't work
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**TABLE Posd**

```
class Posd(models.Model):
#This class is just repsresenting the cost position in KBSUMME
hg = models.IntegerField()
pos = models.IntegerField()
description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
hours = models.CharField(max_length=5)
cost = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('hg', 'pos'),)
```

**TABLE KbMeta**

```
class KbMeta(models.Model):
#This class is representing the meta data for one project. One row per project only.
pid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
klaversion = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
calcbase = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
contractbase = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
quotno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
datecalc = models.DateField(default='1999-09-09')
dateupload = models.DateTimeField(default='1999-09-09')
projname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
customer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
endcustomer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
phase = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

**TABLE Tdb**

```
class Tdb(models.Model):
#This is the T detail cost calculation
hg = models.IntegerField()
pos = models.IntegerField()
hours = models.FloatField()
cost = models.FloatField()
kbmeta = models.ForeignKey(KbMeta, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
posd = models.ManyToManyField(Posd, through='Posd', through_fields=('hg','pos')) # This is wrong, doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

To establish that relation you need to specify an intermediary table as you can see in the documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield). But for that you also need `hg` and `pos` to be a primary key, that's a multiple-column primary key, which django does not support as you can [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/models/#do-django-models-support-multiple-column-primary-keys). The possible solutions that I can see for this are:

1. Modify your Posd and Tbd models so they can relate through an unique column
2. Use raw sql to make `hg` and `pos` a primary key

Comment: Hi Henrique, thanks for your answer. I followed your first suggestion and changed my table structure. Now it works.